# find every possible path in a non oriented graph and weighted

Tags: php, graph, path, dijkstra, weighted

I want to find every possible path in a NON oriented but weighted graph
I have made some search on dijkstra, but I'm only able to find the shortest path, even by looking in the code, i'm not able to find every path (i think it's because of the method used by dijkstra to not search every path)

I know the beginning point, but not the ending point, all I want is no more than X (in weight) in my path (and of the course ALL the path < X)

Let say I have this array to define my point (in php):

```
    $aRoutes = array(
    array(0,0,0),
    array(0,1,10),
    array(0,2,20),
    array(0,3,30),
    array(0,4,100),
    array(1,1,0),
    array(1,2,50),
    array(1,3,15),
    array(1,4,10),
    array(2,2,0), //2->3 is below in the form 3->2
    array(2,4,10),
    array(3,3,0),
    array(3,2,20),//but it's not oriented !
    array(3,4,60),
    array(4,4,0)
    );
```

As you can see, every step have 4 paths reachable.
Now, beginning with step 0, I want to know every path that is less than 50 (if I can have every "longest" that would be the best code ! :) )

In our case every path can be :

```
    0->1 = 10
    0->1->3 = 25
    0->1->3->2 = 45
    0->1->4 = 20
    0->1->4->2 = 30
    0->1->4->2->3 = 50
    0->2 = 20
    0->2->3 = 40
    0->2->4 = 30
    0->3 = 30
    0->3->1 = 45
    0->3->2 = 50
```

As you can see, the "best" one is `0->1->4->2->3 = 50`
(pretty easy to know as it's the longest one)

I'm pretty bad in recursive coding, so that's why I ask your help (i barelly understand what is done in every dijkstra code i have found)

(can be coded in php, java, vb, c, c++, I understand every one and i'm able to translate it once I have it...a little preference for php :p )
Thank in advance for your help

Comment: Now i'm thinking about it, i may need an oriented graph in fact :\ (as i will need to go back to 0 at the end)
As far I have search for now, it seems that i need to use VRPTW (vehicule routing problem with time windows) ... but i'm unable to find some code :p

Comment: Dijkstra's algorithm is to find the shortest path between origin and destination. Is what you are looking to accomplish finding the longest path https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_path_problem ?

Comment: it's not the longest path i want, but the longest "before" a limit (but i will have a look at your link... as far as i read now, it doesn't seems to be what i'm looking for :( thanks anyway :) )